# grailsApplication not available in Domain class when running all Integration tests

Tags: grails, testing, integration-testing

I'm running into a problem when running integration tests in Grails. One of the domain classes in the project has a method that accesses the `grailsApplication.config` property. We have an integration test for one of our services that call this method in the domain class. When the test is run on its own using the command

```
grails test-app integration: com.project.MyTestSpec
```

The test runs fine and the domain class can access `grailsApplication`. However when the whole test suite is run using:

```
grails test-app integration
```

then the test fails with the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'config' on null object
```

When trying to access `grailsApplication.config`. It seems that when the tests are all run together `grailsApplication` is not being injected into the domain class. Has anyone come across this issue before?

From what I have read it seems to be a test pollution issue but as there is no setup happening in each integration test the problem is hard to track down.

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue with grails 3. If you are testing a Domain, you have to setup (testing with spock) at the begining of the test:

```
def setup() {
        Holders.grailsApplication = new DefaultGrailsApplication()
        Holders.grailsApplication.config.property.code = '1234'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue is, but this must be a test pollution issue where yours any one of the test case is doing something with `grailsApplication` using meta class. Because this seems to work fine for me.

As a workaround you can avoid using injected `grailsApplication` and use the `Holders` class instead like the following:

```
package com

import grails.util.Holders

class User {

    // def grailsApplication

    String email
    String name

    String getTitle() {
        return Holders.getConfig()["app.title.prefix"] + name
        // Or
        //return Holders.grailsApplication.config["app.title.prefix"] + name       
    }
}
```

This way, you are not dependent upon the dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that my integrationstest implemented ServiceUnitTest<> which caused the problem.